# Could not get unknown property 'flutter' for extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension

Tags: flutter, android-studio, build.gradle

[1. I treid uninstalling android studio and reinstalling latest version of android studio.
2. tried changing sdk version.
3.even tried changing dependy
and what not
it's been 2 days since i'm trying to solve this error. please help me to get over this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xW7dN.jpg)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\91893\StudioProjects\kuk\android\app\build.gradle' line: 29
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not get unknown property 'flutter' for extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1